# Returning property name from linked class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my application I've got the following classes:

```
public class Area : ModelBase
{
    public Guid AreaTypeId{ get; set; }
    public AreaType AreaType { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
}

public class AreaType : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
}
```

The Area class has a dto like so:

```
public class AreaDto: DtoBase
{
    public Guid AreaTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a specification file for getting the data depending on what data has been provided:

```
public class AreaSpecification : Specification<Area>
{
    public AreaSpecification(AreaFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter.ProjectId != Guid.Empty) {
            Query
                .Where(a => a.AreaType.ProjectId == filter.ProjectId);
        }

        if (filter.AreaTypeId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Query
                .Where(a => a.AreaTypeId == filter.AreaTypeId)
                .Include(a => a.AreaType);
        }
    }
}
```

This is using the Ardalis.specification.

What I would like is that for when the AreaTypeId is provided, it will return the Areas that are using that Id but also the AreaType properties. I thought I would get them by using the:

.Include(a => a.AreaType)

however, the data that is returned is the same regardless of that line being there or not, with the AreaType not showing. What is it I'm missing and how can I get it to display?

If I update the second if statement to:

```
        if (filter.AreaTypeId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Query
                .Where(a => a.AreaType.Id == filter.AreaTypeId);
        }
```

it still works so the AreaType data is there, it's just not displaying

Comment: What is `Query`? Whatever it is, the code should be something like `Query = Query.Where(...).Include(...)`.

Comment: it is part of the interface ISpecificationBuilder from the namespace Ardalis.Specification.
What you've said is how I have the query though?

Comment: Why would I have to reassign it? It's returning data as it is? Query is part of ISpecificationBuilder, and part of Ardalis.Specification.Specification, Query is defined as:  public virtual ISpecificationBuilder<T> Query { get; }.
It is read only, I cannot reassign it

Comment: It appears that `Where` is an extension method in the library that adds the expression to an internal collection of `WhereExpressions`. IMO, it's very deceptive to use the name `Where` for this, because everybody who's seasoned in LINQ is trained to believe that `Where` doesn't change an existing expression (or Func), but returns a new one. I would have chosen something like `AddWhere` (and `AddInclude`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my mistake. In my AreaDto file I did not add a property for displaying the AreaType name. So once I updated my dto like so:

```
 public class AreaDto: DtoBase
{
    public Guid AreaTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string AreaTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

and then did my query like:

```
        if (filter.AreaTypeId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Query
                .Where(a => a.AreaType.Id == filter.AreaTypeId)
                .Include(a => a.AreaType);
        }
```

it shows the data that I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

To include the `AreaType` properties in the result, you can modify your `AreaSpecification` to use the Include method along with the `ThenInclude` method:

```
public class AreaSpecification : Specification<Area>
{
    public AreaSpecification(AreaFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter.ProjectId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Query = Query
                .Include(a => a.AreaType)
                .ThenInclude(at => at.Project)
                .Where(a => a.AreaType.ProjectId == filter.ProjectId);
        }

        if (filter.AreaTypeId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Query = Query
                .Include(a => a.AreaType)
                .Where(a => a.AreaTypeId == filter.AreaTypeId);
        }
    }
}
```